# Which program for a DCC-MIDAS model?

Tags: volatility, correlation, estimation, covariance-matrix

for a thesis research, I plan to use a DCC-MIDAS model. The program I was working with (STATA) is not able to run this. 
Do you have any suggestions as to which program is best for this analysis?

Cheers

Comment: A Google search turns up this as one of the first results: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45150-midas-matlab-toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

R is a good option, with the midasr package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/midasr/index.html